# SQL junction query

Tags: mysql, sql, junction-table, junction

I'm very new to SQL and I'trying to do a query on the data that I've entered to find bottles of wine sold by Danmurphys that are less than $20. The query I've composed is down the bottom but the syntax isn't right and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help you could offer me would be much appreciated!

---

```
CREATE TABLE Retailer
(RETAIL_ID NVARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
RETAIL_NAME NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (RETAIL_ID));

CREATE TABLE Wine
(WINE_ID NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
WINE_NAME NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
WINE_VINT NVARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(WINE_ID));

CREATE TABLE Dist
(RETAIL_ID NVARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
WINE_ID NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
WINE_PRICE DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Dist PRIMARY KEY
    (
        RETAIL_ID,
        WINE_ID
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY (RETAIL_ID) REFERENCES Retailer (RETAIL_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (WINE_ID) REFERENCES Wine (WINE_ID));

INSERT INTO Wine VALUES('101','Grange','2010');
INSERT INTO Wine VALUES('102','Grange','2006');
INSERT INTO Wine VALUES('103','Reserve Shiraz','2013');
INSERT INTO Wine VALUES('104','Grey Label Shiraz','2012');
INSERT INTO Wine VALUES('105','Patricia Shiraz','2009');
INSERT INTO Wine VALUES('106','Ten Acres Shiraz','2012');
INSERT INTO Wine VALUES('107','Double Barrel Shiraz','2012');
INSERT INTO Wine VALUES('108','Platinum Label Shiraz','2006');

INSERT INTO Retailer VALUES('1001', 'Dan Murphys');
INSERT INTO Retailer VALUES('1002', 'Woolworths');

INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1001','101','750');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1001','102','700');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1001','103','10');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1001','104','35');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1001','105','50');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1001','106','25');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1001','107','15');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1001','108','170');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1002','103','9');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1002','104','33');
INSERT INTO Dist VALUES('1002','105','44');

SELECT DISTINCT Wine.WINE_NAME, Wine.WINE_VINT, Dist.WINE_PRICE
FROM Wine
WHERE WINE_PRICE < 20
INNER JOIN Dist ON Wine.WINE_ID = Dist.RETAIL_ID
INNER JOIN Wine on Dist.RETAIL_ID = Retailer.RETAIL_ID
WHERE retailer.RETAIL_NAME = 'danmurphys'
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. During string comparison, it needs to match with what we have in the database. You may write the query in the following way:

```
SELECT Wine.WINE_NAME, Wine.WINE_VINT, Dist.WINE_PRICE
FROM Wine
INNER JOIN Dist ON (Wine.WINE_ID = Dist.WINE_ID)
INNER JOIN Retailer on (Dist.RETAIL_ID = Retailer.RETAIL_ID)
WHERE Retailer.RETAIL_NAME = 'Dan Murphys' AND WINE_PRICE < 20
```

Comment: @MichaelHiggon, my pleasure!